# Can you change the DataSourceId of a Gridview dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have the following in an asp.net page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="DateToVisit" 
        DataSourceID="AccessYouthSchedule" AutoGenerateEditButton="True">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Observer" HeaderText="Observer" SortExpression="Observer" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DateToVisit" HeaderText="DateToVisit" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DateToVisit" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="YouthClass" HeaderText="YouthClass" SortExpression="YouthClass" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DidVisitOccur" HeaderText="DidVisitOccur" SortExpression="DidVisitOccur" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="IdForEmail" HeaderText="IdForEmail" SortExpression="IdForEmail" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="WeekBeforeNoticeSent" HeaderText="WeekBeforeNoticeSent" SortExpression="WeekBeforeNoticeSent" />
            <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="DayOfNoticeSent" HeaderText="DayOfNoticeSent" SortExpression="DayOfNoticeSent" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PlanToVisit" HeaderText="PlanToVisit" SortExpression="PlanToVisit" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessYouthSchedule" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/SundaySchool.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Observer, [DateToVisit], [YouthClass], [DidVisitOccur], [IdForEmail], [WeekBeforeNoticeSent], [DayOfNoticeSent], [PlanToVisit] FROM [YouthSchedule]"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE YouthSchedule SET Observer = @Observer, YouthClass = @YouthClass, DidiVisitOccur = @DidVisitOccur, IdForEmail = @IdForEmail,
                        WeekBeforeNoticeSent = @WeekBeforeNoticeSent, DayOfNoticeSent = @DayOfNoticeSent, PlanToVisit = @PlanToVisit WHERE DateToVisit = @DateToVisit">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

This works great.  However, I also have other asp:AccessDataSource's that I want to use:

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDoctrineEssentials" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/SundaySchool.mdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [DoctrineObserver1], [DoctrineObserver2], [EssentialsObserver], [DateToVisit] FROM [DoctrineAndEssentials]"
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE DoctrineAndEssentials SET DoctrineObserver1 = @DoctrineObserver, DoctrineObserver2 = @DoctrineObserver2, 
                        EssentialsObserver = @EssentialsObserver WHERE DateToVisit = @DateToVisit">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
```

I can't simply set the GridView1.DataSourceId property due to these 'Columns'.  Is there a way to quickly switch to my other AccessDataSource?  They are mainly just different tables in the same database.

Comment: Not quickly. You'll need to either build multiple grids and hide/show them or you'll need to build the columns in code as well.

Comment: How do you build the columns?  Honestly, it might be easier to just have multiple gridviews...

Comment: You can add the columns with the [`GridView.Columns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.columns(v=vs.110).aspx) accessor, however I think I'd stick with multiple grids. The markup approach is almost certainly a better and more maintainable approach.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud - I have done the very thing you suggested above before.  It's not pretty, it's not easy but, it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest solution here is to use multiple grid views.